# PMD-Eclipse: How to set suppressmarker?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pmd, suppress-warnings

As the [PMD docs](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.0.2/suppressing.html) say,

> you can tell PMD to ignore a specific line by using the "NOPMD" marker

but

> you can use whatever text string you want to suppress warnings

by using the command-line option `-suppressmarker`.

How can you set `-suppressmarker` when using the PMD-Eclipse plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PMD plugin for Eclipse doesn't contain all the options that the command line does.  The easiest thing is to use //NOPMD and ignore the problem completely.

Alternatively, you could use an Ant script to run PMD.  You can set an Ant script to run as a builder for an Eclipse project if you want it to run automatically.  You lose the Eclipse integration with this approach though.  Looking at an HTML report rather than being able to click on the error seems like a big tradeoff just to use a different marker.

Comment: I guess that is the correct answer, though it is not pleasing. We use Sonar and have decided to use //NOSONAR as the only suppression marker. Your answer means we cannot really use PMD in Eclipse. Fortunately, Sonar developers plan to support incremental analysis in the Sonar plugin, so we will have no demand for the PMD plugin in the future.